# How to access the content of a controller based on a property name

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to reuse code in my controllers / templates. In one of my templates, I have the following:

```
{{#if controllers.nodesIndex.content.isUpdating}}
```

This is working fine, but makes this template very specific. I want to generalize this. I would like to do somthing like:

```
{{#if controllers.{{indexController}}.content.isUpdating }}
```

Where `indexController` is actually a config parameter in my controller:

```
indexController : 'nodesIndex',
```

The syntax used is not working, and I do not know if there is a way to do what I am trying to do.

Another thing I have tried is simply:

```
{{#if isUpdating}}
```

And I have defined this as a computed property in the controler. This is the generic setup ("base class"):

```
getIndexController : function () {
    return this.get('controllers.' + this.indexController);
},
isUpdating      : function () { return this.getIndexController().get('content').isUpdating; }.property(),
```

But I am unable to tell `property()` which other properties this computed property depends on, since they are actually configurable, as returned by the `getIndexController()` function.

Any ideas on how to access the content of a "dynamic" controller?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are going to the wrong way. Ember provide some options to you share templates between controllers.

Here I made a example with partial
http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/KxM9k/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Partial example</h1>
    {{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "other"}}Other{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Index template</h2>
  {{partial "updatingMessage"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="other">
  <h2>Other template</h2>
  {{partial "updatingMessage"}}
</script>
```

All options avaliable are in that link http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Comment: I am already using partials / outlets. Still, my top-level templates can be unified in a single template. That is why I want to remove any controller-specific references, and make this configurable in the controller. Just imagine that you want to unify your "index" and your "other" template into a "generic" template. Since I am using separate files for my templates, I hope to be able to use symbolic links to link to a common template - or maybe use another trick.

Answer (score 1):

Having a property on your controller that is the name of the "dynamic" controller is a good place to start. Why not just make your property depend on that?

```
getIndexController : function () {
    return this.get('controllers.' + this.indexController);
},
isUpdating : function () { 
  return this.getIndexController().get('content').isUpdating; 
}.property('indexController'),
```

If you think of "getIndexController" as a helper function then it makes sense. Rolling the two functions together makes it easier to see that the indexController attribute is the only real property that needs to be observed:

```
isUpdating : function () { 
  return this.get('controllers.' + this.indexController).get('content').isUpdating; 
}.property('indexController'),
```

Comment: Not sure this can work at all: `isUpdating` does not depend on the value of `this.indexController`, but on the `isUpdating` property of the `content` of the `controller` specified in `this.indexController`. That is, even if `this.indexController` does not change (which it won't: it is a fixed parameter for a given controller), the `isUpdating` property can very well change, since the referred property in the controller specified in `this.indexController` will change.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in an indirect way, with an observer:

```
isUpdatingChanged: function () {
    this.getTopController().set('isUpdating', this.get('content').get('isUpdating'));
}.observes('content.isUpdating'),
```